# Swiftmailer sending from console but not from PHP

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer, dovecot

I have the following code to send mails:

```
/* Emails */
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('Ihre Sammelrechnung')
        ->setFrom("xxx@myserver.com")
        ->setTo("recipient@gmail.com")
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'email/invoiceMultiFinal.html.twig', array(
                    'company' => 'COMPANY',
                )
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

    /* Send eMail */
    if(!$this->get('mailer')->send($message)){
        die("ERROR");
    }
```

I know 100% that sender an recipient are correct. In my Logs I have:

> {"message":"Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username \"xxx@myserver.com\" using 1 possible authenticators","context":[],"level":400,"level_name":"ERROR","channel":"app","datetime":{"date":"2016-05-31 15:19:09.919207","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe/Berlin"},"extra":[]}

config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
transport: "%mailer_transport%"
host:      "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory } #Deleting this changes nothing
```

parameters.yml

```
parameters:
  mailer_transport: smtp
  mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
  mailer_user: xxx@myserver.com # adding "" doesn't change sth either
  mailer_password: password
 secret: xxxxxxx
```

I am using my own server, so no Gmail etc. involved. I can send and receive emails through the webmailer AND through `php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send`

Any ideas what can cause such behaviour? Side note, it worked like a charm for almost a month! It stopped today, possibly related to a reboot!

Comment: Is it possible that your application is running in prod mode and that you need to clear your cache to reload SMTP settings.